# Поворачивать руку фигуры в соответствии с перемещением курсора мыши

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, svg, svg-animation

У меня есть изображение SVG доктора, которого я хочу немного оживить. Я хочу, чтобы рука указала на мышь. Однако я не могу заставить его правильно работать.
В настоящее время у меня есть следующий код:

[Смотрите Codepen](https://codepen.io/coen-hallie/pen/bGELLGO)

Как видите, рука неподвижна, но плечо свободно перемещается, а должно быть наоборот.  Только когда я указываю мышкой на плечо, рука снова становится правильной.

Я использовал следующий код:

```
document.querySelector('#app')
    .addEventListener('mousemove', mascotArm);
    function mascotArm() {
      var arm = document.querySelectorAll('.arm');
      arm.forEach(function(arm) {
        let x = (arm.getBoundingClientRect().right);
        let y = (arm.getBoundingClientRect().top);
        let radian = Math.atan2(event.pageX - x, event.pageY + y);
        let rot = (radian * (90 / Math.PI))
        arm.style.transform = 'rotate('+ rot + 'deg)';
      })
    }
```

Я попробовал этот код, но я не смог правильно его реализовать в  SVG

```
var cv = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
cv.width = 1224;
cv.height = 768;
document.body.appendChild(cv);

var centerX = 300, centerY = 200;

var arm = new Image();
arm.onload = function() {
    drawArrow(0);
};
var arm = document.querySelectorAll('.arm')


function drawArm(angle) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cv.width, cv.height);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
  ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.drawImage(arm, -arm.width / 2, -arm.height / 2);
  ctx.restore();
}

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var dx = e.pageX - centerX;
  var dy = e.pageY - centerY;
  var theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    drawArm(theta);
};
```

**Желаемое решение**

Я хочу получить решение, которое состояло бы в том, чтобы я мог перемещать курсор мышки на странице, и  рука указывала бы синхронно  на изменения положения курсора. Если это возможно, было бы здорово, если бы рука могла бы двигаться только на 90 градусов вверх и вниз, чтобы она не совершала странных поворотов.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Make arm point towards mouse direction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62743529/7394871) от участника  [@Coen Hallie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13746380/coen-hallie).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62743529/7394871

Answer (score 6):

Вам понадобится преобразование `transform origin` (начала координат) для вращения руки `.arm`.
Например, вы можете попробовать `.arm {transform-origin: 280px 200px;}`.
В коде я добавил маленький красный круг, чтобы отметить центр вращения. Вы можете удалить круг и изменить положение центра вращения. Обратите внимание, что я использую положение центра вращения в JavaScript. Тебе тоже придется это поменять.

В JavaScript это `Math.atan2 (y, x)`, а не `Math.atan2 (x, y)`. Пожалуйста, прочитайте о [Math.atan2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2).
Также рука имеет другой угол внутри контейнера `.arm`. Вам нужно будет принять во внимание и этот угол.
Чтобы понять, что происходит, я добавил черный прямоугольник размером с ограничивающую рамку руки.
Вы можете попробовать `arm.style.transform = 'rotate (' + (rot - 20) + 'deg)';`

Также вы слушаете мышь над приложением. Как вы можете видеть, я слушаю мышь над SVG Elemet. Я полагаю, вам нужен доктор в правой части приложения. Чтобы разместить его там, я применяю `#app {height: 100vh;` Приложение теперь так же широко, как и его родитель.

Также у svg `{width: 100%; height: 100%}` Это растянет элемент svg над приложением. Чтобы позиционировать доктора справа, я использую `preserveAspectRatio = "xMaxYMax meet"`

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('#svg'); svg.addEventListener('mousemove', mascotArm);
//the hub position
let X = 280;
let Y = 200;

    function mascotArm(event) {
      var arm = document.querySelector('.arm');
       let p = getMousePositionSVG(event)
        let x = p.x;
        let y = p.y;
        let radian = Math.atan2(Y-y, X-x);
        let rot = (radian * (180 / Math.PI))
        arm.style.transform = 'rotate('+ (rot - 20) + 'deg)';
      
    }

//функция для вычисления положения мыши над элементом SVG
function getMousePositionSVG(event) {
var point = svg.createSVGPoint();
point.x = event.clientX;
point.y = event.clientY;
point = point.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
return point;
}
```

```css
#app {
  background: #efefef;
  height:100vh 
}
svg{width:100%; height:100%}
.arm{transform-origin: 280px 200px;
```

```html
<div id="app">
<svg viewBox="0 0 458 753" fill="none" id="svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet">
  <g class="Layer 1">
    <g class="Group">
      <g class="Group_2">
        <g class="Group_3">
          <path d="M286.306 353l-18.063 197.3-14.569 144.54s7.896 11 37.606 6l15.695-151.5 19.149-124.5h15.299l10.167 276s12.831 10 36.619 1l-4.737-355.3-97.166 6.46z" fill="#303942" class="Vector_7"/>
          <path d="M373.265 701.34a48.73 48.73 0 0014.609-2.5l-4.639-347.6-89.033 5.9-17.767 193.7-14.312 142.4c2.171 1.6 7.6 4.7 18.853 4.7a73.728 73.728 0 0010.462-.8l15.3-148.3 19.741-128.2h22.998l10.266 277.8a29.95 29.95 0 0013.522 2.9z" fill="#252D33" class="Vector_8"/>
          <path d="M274.856 199.44s3.257 100.3 9.673 151.2c0 0 24.479 11.1 63.566 9.5 27.638-1.1 35.534-7.1 35.534-7.1l40.075-162.7s-20.432-11.9-62.481-11.9l-19.543 18.3s-5.331-14.2-15.793-17c-15.793 1.1-32.277 6-50.834 9.1l-.197 10.6z" fill="#148C78" class="Vector_9"/>
          <path d="M341.778 196.64l5.034-17.8 11.154 5.2-16.188 12.6z" fill="#056351" class="Vector_10"/>
          <path d="M349.477 161.24c4.936-2.4 9.476-6.9 12.931-13l.493 2.6.296 25.5c-8.982 1.2-19.247-4.1-28.526-14.6a17.467 17.467 0 007.458 1.399 17.467 17.467 0 007.348-1.899z" fill="#F2957C" class="Vector_11"/>
          <path d="M340.298 180.44l1.48 16.2-9.179-11.5 7.699-4.7z" fill="#056351" class="Vector_12"/>
          <path d="M350.168 185.14a41.914 41.914 0 01-13.226.5l-6.219 7.5 5.429 7.9-21.222 125.3 16.385 16.6 20.038-14.5-4.639-126.6 6.81-9.8-3.356-6.9z" fill="#73C8D2" class="Vector_13"/>
          <path d="M315.029 179.34l13.72 18.8 11.549-17.7-18.162-12.3-7.107 11.2z" fill="#0C7561" class="Vector_14"/>
          <path d="M412.353 247.44l-19.445 75 6.712 198.2-66.33 14.6-9.674-19.7-9.673 20.9-54.683-13.8s13.424-289.4 15.892-333.6l28.032-9.1 34.547 115.5 41.299-118.2s43.43 11.8 53.794 14.4" fill="#E5E5E5" class="Vector_16"/>
          <path d="M335.165 164.64c17.964-2.3 38.199-17.3 42.838-27a17.044 17.044 0 012.863-4.6c16.385 3 24.38-31.4 13.621-36.1-.395-.2-.888-.3-1.283-.5a10.522 10.522 0 017.6.5c10.759 4.7 2.863 39.1-13.621 36.1a15.652 15.652 0 00-2.863 4.6c-4.639 9.8-24.873 24.7-42.838 27a33.045 33.045 0 01-7.699.1c.463.016.926-.017 1.382-.1z" fill="#F4876C" class="Vector_17"/>
          <path d="M399.225 102.84c-5.626-2.9-10.562 6.3-10.858 16.1 4.639-.7 5.429 4.7 2.764 8.6 9.278 1.9 14.115-21.6 8.094-24.7z" fill="#F2957C" class="Vector_18"/>
          <path d="M432.884 191.64c-8.094-2.1-40.174-13.5-53.795-14.4l-41.259 118.1-34.547-115.5-17.471 44c-2.171 40.1-18.359 258.6-20.235 295l46.491 12.4 11.154-23.6 11.943 22.3 61.888-15.3 4.442-196.4 14.411-98.3" fill="#F2F2F2" class="Vector_19"/>
          <g class="Group_6">
            <path d="M375.733 274.74v-8.2h-6.811a2.956 2.956 0 01-1.923-1.186 3.028 3.028 0 01-.544-2.214 2.887 2.887 0 01.808-1.681 2.824 2.824 0 011.659-.819h19.544a2.935 2.935 0 012.018.674c.567.47.942 1.136 1.053 1.87a3.035 3.035 0 01-.455 2.103 2.964 2.964 0 01-1.728 1.253h-7.6v8.2a3.118 3.118 0 01-1.064 1.796 3.04 3.04 0 01-3.893 0 3.118 3.118 0 01-1.064-1.796zm-6.811-12.8a1.664 1.664 0 00-1.215.427c-.333.3-.535.722-.561 1.173-.027.451.125.894.421 1.231.296.338.713.542 1.158.569h8.39v9.4c.038.446.243.861.573 1.159.331.298.762.455 1.204.441a1.774 1.774 0 001.066-.519c.287-.291.468-.672.513-1.081v-9.4h8.094c.445.027.882-.127 1.215-.427.333-.3.535-.722.561-1.173a1.711 1.711 0 00-.421-1.231 1.674 1.674 0 00-1.158-.569h-19.84z" fill="#006983" class="Vector_20"/>
            <path d="M368.922 260.64h19.544a2.935 2.935 0 012.018.674c.567.47.942 1.136 1.053 1.87a3.035 3.035 0 01-.455 2.103 2.964 2.964 0 01-1.728 1.253h-7.6v8.2a3.007 3.007 0 01-1.171 1.949 2.931 2.931 0 01-2.185.551 2.943 2.943 0 01-1.636-.843 3.015 3.015 0 01-.832-1.657v-8.2h-6.771a2.954 2.954 0 01-1.924-1.186 3.028 3.028 0 01-.543-2.214 2.433 2.433 0 01.629-1.721 2.375 2.375 0 011.641-.779h-.04zm.04-1.2c-1.1 0-2.154.443-2.932 1.23a4.23 4.23 0 00-1.214 2.97 4.23 4.23 0 001.214 2.97 4.118 4.118 0 002.932 1.23h5.626v6.9a4.254 4.254 0 001.361 2.904 4.147 4.147 0 002.982 1.096 4.073 4.073 0 002.751-1.213 4.174 4.174 0 001.197-2.787v-6.9h5.626c1.1 0 2.154-.442 2.932-1.23a4.23 4.23 0 001.214-2.97 4.23 4.23 0 00-1.214-2.97 4.123 4.123 0 00-2.932-1.23h-19.543z" fill="#fff" class="Vector_21"/>
            <path d="M368.922 259.44h19.544c1.1 0 2.154.443 2.931 1.23a4.227 4.227 0 011.215 2.97 4.227 4.227 0 01-1.215 2.97 4.114 4.114 0 01-2.931 1.23h-5.626v6.9a4.254 4.254 0 01-1.361 2.904 4.147 4.147 0 01-2.982 1.096 4.069 4.069 0 01-2.751-1.213 4.17 4.17 0 01-1.197-2.787v-6.9h-5.627a4.15 4.15 0 01-2.923-1.239 4.258 4.258 0 01-1.222-2.961 4.187 4.187 0 011.202-2.982 4.095 4.095 0 012.943-1.218zm0-1.3a5.35 5.35 0 00-2.08.413 5.41 5.41 0 00-1.764 1.192 5.485 5.485 0 00-1.177 1.787 5.554 5.554 0 00-.407 2.108 5.475 5.475 0 00.391 2.117 5.424 5.424 0 001.175 1.796 5.334 5.334 0 001.772 1.19 5.28 5.28 0 002.09.397h4.343v5.7a5.492 5.492 0 001.686 3.646 5.354 5.354 0 003.694 1.484 5.354 5.354 0 003.694-1.484 5.496 5.496 0 001.685-3.646v-5.7h4.343a5.351 5.351 0 002.081-.413 5.42 5.42 0 001.764-1.192 5.482 5.482 0 001.176-1.787 5.536 5.536 0 00.408-2.108 5.475 5.475 0 00-.391-2.117 5.424 5.424 0 00-1.175-1.796 5.328 5.328 0 00-3.863-1.587h-19.445z" fill="#006983" class="Vector_22"/>
            <path d="M378.595 249.44c.391 0 .773.117 1.097.337a2.019 2.019 0 01.299 3.077 1.956 1.956 0 01-3.037-.303 2.017 2.017 0 01.246-2.525 1.96 1.96 0 011.395-.586zm0-1.2c-.644 0-1.273.194-1.809.556a3.295 3.295 0 00-1.2 1.481 3.343 3.343 0 00-.185 1.907c.125.64.436 1.228.891 1.689a3.219 3.219 0 003.55.716 3.27 3.27 0 001.462-1.216c.358-.542.549-1.18.549-1.833a3.32 3.32 0 00-.24-1.268 3.268 3.268 0 00-.705-1.074 3.216 3.216 0 00-2.313-.958z" fill="#006983" class="Vector_23"/>
            <path d="M378.595 248.24c.645 0 1.274.194 1.81.556.536.363.953.878 1.2 1.481.246.603.311 1.267.185 1.907a3.316 3.316 0 01-.891 1.689 3.219 3.219 0 01-3.55.716 3.27 3.27 0 01-1.462-1.216 3.327 3.327 0 01-.549-1.833 3.423 3.423 0 01.982-2.306 3.334 3.334 0 012.275-.994zm0-1.3c-.878 0-1.737.264-2.467.758a4.489 4.489 0 00-1.636 2.02 4.56 4.56 0 00-.253 2.6 4.508 4.508 0 001.216 2.304 4.389 4.389 0 004.84.975 4.45 4.45 0 001.994-1.657c.488-.74.748-1.61.748-2.5a4.585 4.585 0 00-1.315-3.168 4.461 4.461 0 00-3.127-1.332z" fill="#fff" class="Vector_24"/>
            <path d="M378.595 246.94c.879 0 1.738.264 2.468.758a4.489 4.489 0 011.636 2.02 4.56 4.56 0 01.253 2.6 4.523 4.523 0 01-1.216 2.304 4.389 4.389 0 01-4.84.975 4.45 4.45 0 01-1.994-1.657 4.542 4.542 0 01-.748-2.5 4.636 4.636 0 011.331-3.151 4.522 4.522 0 013.11-1.349zm0-1.2c-1.132 0-2.239.34-3.18.977a5.794 5.794 0 00-2.109 2.603 5.875 5.875 0 00-.325 3.352 5.818 5.818 0 001.566 2.969 5.66 5.66 0 006.239 1.257 5.742 5.742 0 002.57-2.136 5.854 5.854 0 00.964-3.222 5.84 5.84 0 00-1.676-4.101 5.688 5.688 0 00-4.049-1.699z" fill="#006983" class="Vector_25"/>
          </g>
          <path d="M303.184 179.84l34.547 115.5-30.302-37.4 2.369-24.6-16.089-4.9 1.579-47.3 7.896-1.3z" fill="#E5E5E5" class="Vector_26"/>
          <path d="M303.382 180.14l-4.343.7-1.086 43.8 15.892 5-2.567 25.4 22.999 28.4-30.895-103.3z" fill="#EAEAEA" class="Vector_27"/>
          <path d="M333.092 318.34c2.508 0 4.541-2.059 4.541-4.6 0-2.541-2.033-4.6-4.541-4.6-2.507 0-4.54 2.059-4.54 4.6 0 2.541 2.033 4.6 4.54 4.6z" fill="#E8E8E8" class="Vector_28"/>
          <path d="M331.019 349.04c2.508 0 4.541-2.06 4.541-4.6 0-2.541-2.033-4.6-4.541-4.6-2.507 0-4.54 2.059-4.54 4.6 0 2.54 2.033 4.6 4.54 4.6z" fill="#E8E8E8" class="Vector_29"/>
          <path d="M329.637 381.04c2.508 0 4.541-2.06 4.541-4.6 0-2.541-2.033-4.6-4.541-4.6-2.507 0-4.54 2.059-4.54 4.6 0 2.54 2.033 4.6 4.54 4.6z" fill="#E8E8E8" class="Vector_30"/>
          <path d="M327.565 411.74c2.507 0 4.54-2.06 4.54-4.6 0-2.541-2.033-4.6-4.54-4.6-2.508 0-4.541 2.059-4.541 4.6 0 2.54 2.033 4.6 4.541 4.6z" fill="#E8E8E8" class="Vector_31"/>
          <path d="M326.676 439.34c2.508 0 4.541-2.059 4.541-4.6 0-2.541-2.033-4.6-4.541-4.6-2.507 0-4.54 2.059-4.54 4.6 0 2.541 2.033 4.6 4.54 4.6z" fill="#E8E8E8" class="Vector_32"/>
          <path d="M324.505 470.04c2.507 0 4.54-2.06 4.54-4.6 0-2.541-2.033-4.6-4.54-4.6-2.508 0-4.541 2.059-4.541 4.6 0 2.54 2.033 4.6 4.541 4.6z" fill="#E8E8E8" class="Vector_33"/>
          <path d="M323.222 498.24c2.507 0 4.54-2.06 4.54-4.6 0-2.541-2.033-4.6-4.54-4.6-2.508 0-4.541 2.059-4.541 4.6 0 2.54 2.033 4.6 4.541 4.6z" fill="#E8E8E8" class="Vector_34"/>
          <path d="M352.142 88.24c2.567-2.3 8.686-1.8 10.364.6.889.6 0 1.8-1.776 1.8h-3.415a3.91 3.91 0 00-2.567.6c-1.717-.1-4.343-1.9-2.606-3z" fill="#65433F" class="Vector_35"/>
          <path d="M332.895 120c.789 0 2.27 1.6 3.06 1.6 1.48 0 2.27 0 3.059-.8.79-.8 2.271 0 1.58 1.6-.691 1.6-3.06 2.5-4.639 2.5-1.58 0-4.64-1.6-5.33-3.3.789-.76 1.48-1.6 2.27-1.6z" fill="#F4876C" class="Vector_36"/>
          <path d="M332.796 153.74l1.086-1.1c1.086 0 2.171 2.3 1.086 2.3h-2.172c0-.1-1.086-.1 0-1.2z" fill="#F4876C" class="Vector_37"/>
          <path d="M396.955 104.84a4.065 4.065 0 00-1.913-.537 4.062 4.062 0 00-1.937.437c1.777-2 3.948-2.8 6.219-1.6 5.231 2.7 2.171 21-4.738 24.3 5.172-5.7 6.909-20.2 2.369-22.6z" fill="#E58370" class="Vector_38"/>
          <path d="M322.037 88.34c-2.566-2.4-8.686-1.8-10.364.6-.888.6 0 1.8 1.777 1.8h3.454a3.91 3.91 0 012.567.6c1.776-.1 4.343-1.9 2.566-3z" fill="#65433F" class="Vector_39"/>
          <path d="M378.99 177.24l6.811.3 3.948 42.4-19.642 4.4 6.712 26.4-37.212 39.3 39.383-112.8z" fill="#E5E5E5" class="Vector_40"/>
          <path d="M373.167 247.94l-6.91-27.4 19.939-4.5-3.554-38.6-3.454-.2-35.534 101.9 29.513-31.2z" fill="#EAEAEA" class="Vector_41"/>
        <path d="M296.176 190.54h-.395a19.546 19.546 0 00-13.621 5.5c-10.463 10.1-9.377 30.6-9.278 31.5.093.656.432 1.251.947 1.66.514.41 1.165.603 1.816.54a2.41 2.41 0 001.754-.723 2.49 2.49 0 00.714-1.777c0-.3-1.086-19.4 7.897-28a13.675 13.675 0 014.593-2.975 13.54 13.54 0 015.376-.925h.197a13.562 13.562 0 018.291 3.1c4.146 3.3 9.18 10.9 9.575 27.9a2.61 2.61 0 00.921 1.718c.516.43 1.177.638 1.843.582a2.36 2.36 0 001.798-.635 2.423 2.423 0 00.768-1.765c-.395-15.1-4.244-25.7-11.549-31.4a18.149 18.149 0 00-11.647-4.3z" fill="#006983" class="Vector_67"/>
        <g class="Group_13">
          <path d="M293.807 255.34a2.381 2.381 0 00-.714-1.647 2.311 2.311 0 00-1.655-.653l-4.245.5c-1.283.4-1.283 1.1-1.283 2 0 1 0 1.7 1.481 2l4.145.2a2.36 2.36 0 001.609-.74c.423-.447.66-1.041.662-1.66z" fill="#151E31" class="Vector_68"/>
          <path d="M290.55 255.44a2.712 2.712 0 012.27 1c-.418.429-.984.68-1.579.7l-2.566-.1c-.099-1.2.592-1.6 1.875-1.6z" fill="#fff" class="Vector_69"/>
          <path d="M289.563 254.24c-1.875.3-2.566 1.6-2.566 3.3-1.185-.3-1.185-1-1.185-1.9 0-.9 0-1.6 1.283-2l4.245-.5c.522 0 1.03.177 1.441.504.411.326.703.782.829 1.296a4.596 4.596 0 00-4.047-.7z" fill="#808184" class="Vector_70"/>
        </g>
        <g class="Group_14">
          <path d="M298.841 255.24a2.375 2.375 0 01.645-1.677 2.32 2.32 0 011.626-.723l4.343.3c1.381.3 1.283 1 1.381 1.9 0 1 0 1.7-1.381 2.1l-4.146.4a2.458 2.458 0 01-1.676-.663 2.523 2.523 0 01-.792-1.637z" fill="#151E31" class="Vector_71"/>
          <path d="M302.099 255.14a2.272 2.272 0 00-2.172 1.1c.429.401.996.616 1.579.6l2.567-.3c0-1.2-.691-1.54-1.974-1.4z" fill="#fff" class="Vector_72"/>
          <path d="M303.027 253.84c.379.016.751.11 1.094.277a2.8 2.8 0 01.897.692 2.851 2.851 0 01.674 2.131c1.184-.4 1.184-1.1 1.086-2-.099-.9 0-1.6-1.382-1.9l-4.343-.3a2.218 2.218 0 00-1.428.549c-.397.348-.66.826-.744 1.351a5.713 5.713 0 014.146-.8z" fill="#808184" class="Vector_73"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g class="ster-ogen">
      <path d="M318.43 112.35l8.72 3.42-3.63-8.61 6-7.27-9.34.73-5-7.89-2.18 9-9 2.28 8 4.88-.62 9.34 7.05-5.88z" fill="#F9FF00" class="Vector_74"/>
      <path d="M361.98 119.3l-.62-10 8.51-5.19-9.65-2.49-2.24-9.62-5.3 8.31-9.86-.83 6.33 7.68-3.84 9.13 9.24-3.63 7.43 6.64z" fill="#F9FF00" class="Vector_75"/>
    </g>
    <g class="blij">
      <path d="M334.671 148.64c-11.055-1.1-12.733-9-11.055-11.2 1.678-2.2 19.939-2.3 22.209 0 1.619 1.7-.592 11.2-11.154 11.2z" fill="#AA312D" class="Vector_76"/>
      <path d="M346.319 139.14a1.93 1.93 0 00-.592-1.7c-2.271-2.3-19.939-2.3-22.209 0 0 0-.593 1.1 0 1.7 7.304 2.2 15.102 1.7 22.801 0z" fill="#fff" class="Vector_77"/>
      <path d="M330.723 147.84a12.667 12.667 0 01-4.836-2.6c.493-.5 1.085-.5 1.579-1.1a17.076 17.076 0 015.527-.6 13.086 13.086 0 018.588 3.2 12.866 12.866 0 01-6.91 1.9 13.294 13.294 0 01-3.454-.7.884.884 0 01-.494-.1z" fill="#902622" class="Vector_78"/>
    </g>
    <g class="ogen">
      <path d="M358.065 113.64c4.143 0 7.501-3.627 7.501-8.1 0-4.474-3.358-8.1-7.501-8.1-4.143 0-7.502 3.626-7.502 8.1 0 4.473 3.359 8.1 7.502 8.1z" fill="#F2957C" class="Vector_79"/>
      <path d="M358.065 112.44c3.543 0 6.416-3.089 6.416-6.9 0-3.811-2.873-6.9-6.416-6.9-3.544 0-6.416 3.089-6.416 6.9 0 3.811 2.872 6.9 6.416 6.9z" fill="#5E3536" class="Vector_80"/>
      <path d="M360.039 104.14c.872 0 1.579-.761 1.579-1.7s-.707-1.7-1.579-1.7-1.579.761-1.579 1.7.707 1.7 1.579 1.7z" fill="#fff" class="Vector_81"/>
      <path d="M316.707 113.64c4.143 0 7.502-3.627 7.502-8.1 0-4.474-3.359-8.1-7.502-8.1s-7.502 3.626-7.502 8.1c0 4.473 3.359 8.1 7.502 8.1z" fill="#F2957C" class="Vector_82"/>
      <path d="M316.707 112.44c3.543 0 6.416-3.089 6.416-6.9 0-3.811-2.873-6.9-6.416-6.9s-6.416 3.089-6.416 6.9c0 3.811 2.873 6.9 6.416 6.9z" fill="#5E3536" class="Vector_83"/>
      <path d="M318.681 104.14c.872 0 1.579-.761 1.579-1.7s-.707-1.7-1.579-1.7-1.579.761-1.579 1.7.707 1.7 1.579 1.7z" fill="#fff" class="Vector_84"/>
    </g>
    <g class="arm" id="kk">
      <rect y="109" width="282" height="128" fill="black"/>
      <path d="M75.77 140.4l-8.785-3.8s-8.983-13.4-21.222-17.2a79.917 79.917 0 01-8.193-2.9 16.65 16.65 0 01-6.81-7.5s-5.627.5-1.481 7.8a22.565 22.565 0 006.613 6.4 67.371 67.371 0 01-10.759-3.4c-1.776-.8-12.437-5-16.385-6.9-1.875-.9-6.712-3.3-8.489.4-1.974 4.2 7.897 7.6 10.068 8.4 4.738 1.9 16.78 8.8 16.78 8.8s-8.093-2.6-9.475 2.2a4.26 4.26 0 00.296 3.1c1.184 2.4 2.862 2.5 2.862 2.5a4.809 4.809 0 00-1.579 2.521 4.86 4.86 0 00.197 2.979 5.87 5.87 0 001.962 2.366 5.76 5.76 0 002.875 1.034s-4.442 5.6 3.948 9c2.863 1.2 4.935 1.3 7.897 1.8 2.888.601 5.843.802 8.784.6a48.873 48.873 0 009.377-.9c1.876-.4 7.009 3.1 9.772 5.2a22.152 22.152 0 005.824 3.2l11.845-23.4-5.923-2.3z" fill="#F2AB8F" class="Vector_85"/>
      <path d="M84.949 140.3l-8.982-4.2-14.806 31.4 9.377 5.2 14.41-32.4z" fill="#148C78" class="Vector_86"/>
      <path d="M273.97 233.6l8.193-41.3s-168.984-14.9-194.55-56.5c0 0-19.938 21.6-22.307 37.7-.098 0 175.795 76.3 208.664 60.1z" fill="#F2F2F2" class="Vector_87"/>
      <path d="M254.328 237.2c-36.028-1.5-144.308-43-190.403-62.3 1.875-3.4 2.171-8.1 4.639-11.6 18.556 14.8 66.034 33.9 116.867 43.9 29.908 5.9 78.965 10.9 95.35 12.8l-.691 16c-5.231 1.2-25.071 1.2-25.762 1.2z" fill="#E5E5E5" class="Vector_88"/>
    </g>
  </g>
    
    <circle cx="280" cy="200" r="10" fill="red"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Make arm point towards mouse direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62744091/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>

Comment: не плохой пример... но с точки зрения анатомии, это мутант...)))  Привет Александр...

Comment: @Air Привет Норик! Ну да, картинка не очень, но можно поискать другую, а решение оставить то же